# jQuery showing the Too much recursion in error console

Tags: jquery

I have written a tool tip snippet, its throwing error like TOO MUCH RECURSION ERROR ,

How to fix this error?

Here is the URL please look thanks

[plz look this](http://www.happylife.in/onover.html)

Comment: Did you tried removing the onmousemove event??

Comment: not seeing any errors using ff 3.6.3 ... which browser do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
onmouseout="onmouseout();"
```

to something like

```
onmouseout="onmouseoutfncall();"
```

Also you don't have to each time append and remove the tool tip. Just show and hide that.

```
$("a.screenshot").hover(function(){
    var title_a = $(".screenshot").attr("rel");
    var tip = $("#screenshot");
    tip.children("span").text(title_a);
    tip.show();                              
}
},
function(){
    var tip = $("#screenshot");
    tip.hide();
}).bind("mousemove", function(){
    $("#screenshot").css({"top": "41px", "left": "41px"}).fadeIn("fast");
});

<p id='screenshot'><SPAN></SPAN></p>
```

Comment: i thing some other script stopping my tooltip...
can you please refer very simple tool tip snippet, 
Thanks